# Lint check potential plurals?

Tags: android-resources, lint

My Lintcheck complains regarding my string resources.

> Potential Plurals res/values/strings.xml Formatting %d followed by
>   words ("Pers"): This should probably be a plural rather than a string

This Resource was previously a , but I changed this to a normal string like:

```
<string name="plain_string">%d Pers</string>
```

I would understand a warning, but a error? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 27):

Convert the string to a plural like descriped [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals):

```
<plurals name="plain_string">
    <item quantity="one">%d Pers</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d Pers</item>
</plurals>
```

In your code you have to replace

```
getContext().getString(R.string.plain_string, pers)
```

by

```
getContext().getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.plain_string, pers, pers)
```

Or just suppress the warning like this:

```
<string name="plain_string" tools:ignore="PluralsCandidate">%d Pers</string>
```

Kotlin extension that handles null and automatically passes in count for strings with formatting:

```
// note: these methods won't work if you have multiple formats in your string

// plural strings without formatted count ("book", "books")
fun Context.getQuantityString(resId: Int, maybeCount: Int?, defaultCount: Int = 0): String? {
    val count = maybeCount ?: defaultCount
    return resources?.getQuantityString(resId, count, count)
}

// plural strings with formatted count (e.g. "%d book", "%d books")
fun Context.getPluralString(resId: Int, maybeCount: Int?, defaultCount: Int = 0): String? {
    return resources?.getQuantityString(resId, maybeCount ?: defaultCount)
}

// usage
context?.getQuantityString(R.plurals.words_count, nullableCount)
```

Comment: Change in xml for textview is as follows- 
from            android:text="@string/plain_string"
to            android:text="@plurals/plain_string"

Comment: "When using the getQuantityString() method, you need to pass the count twice if your string includes string formatting with a number. For example, for the string %d songs found, the first count parameter selects the appropriate plural string and the second count parameter is inserted into the %d placeholder." https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#Plurals